# A value of type '<null>' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, nullable

I am getting the Error:

> A value of type '' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'T'

while trying to write this piece of code

```
protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, T defaultValueIfNull = null);
```

Does anybody has idea that how to make null value types. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: `protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, T defaultValueIfNull = null) where T:class`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are no constraints on type `T`, so it can be a value type.

You can rewrite method definition as

```
protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property, T defaultValueIfNull = default(T));
```

Which will mean `null` for reference types and default value for value types.

Comment: actually, if you are not going to pass value types to this method, will be better to add constraint on method or (if type T is defined by class) on class.

Answer (score 10):

`T` in this case might also be a value type, such as `int`, which cannot be `null`. You should specify a type constraint, limiting `T` to classes:

```
...T defaultValueIfNull = null) where T : class
```

An alternative would be using `...T defaultValueIfNull = default(T))` - you wouldn't need the constraint, but value types would become `0` by default, instead of `null`.